# Modify a tag name that is associated with a class

Tags: javascript, css, tags

so lets say I have the situation such as this

```js
document.getElementsbyClassName(".wrapper img").style.width = "20px"
```

```css
.wrapper img {
  width: 10px;
  }
```

I want to be able to edit the .wrapper img only. So to do that I need to include the tag associated with the class name. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.querySelectorAll` instead of `.getElementsByClassName`.

- `.querySelectorAll` does a selector query, just like CSS and a jQuery selector.
- `.getElementsByClassName` only grabs class names, that's why you don't use the dot when searching a class. *(Same restriction for getElementById or getElementsByTagName, they only return simple queries)*.

  Example: `<div class="box">`, `document.getElementsByClassName('box');`

Also, remember that, aside from `getElementById` *(notice Element is singular)* all other query will return an array. So you must specify just what element you wish to edit. Normally [0] or if you wish to edit them all, just loop through the array.

[Here's an example code](https://jsfiddle.net/cz7b70v6/).

Comment: my concern is how do I go about changing the style of the ".wrapper img "without changing anything in the general ".wrapper"

Comment: The above solution should work. However when returning queries other than getElementById, it returns an array. So you must access it with [0], assuming you want to change just the first element. I'll set up an example.